# Split a single sql column into five

Tags: sql, google-cloud-sql, legacy-sql

I'm trying to split one column into up to five around the " > " delimiter but the things I've tried haven'tw orked:

I tried

```
select
id, 
compoundColumn,
split(compoundColumn," > ")[1] as "first"
split(compoundColumn," > ")[2] as "second"
from table
where compoundColumn is not null
```

which didn't work, and

this which sort of did (the first part anyway, not the nth part)

```
select
id, 
compoundColumn,
first(split(compoundColumn," > ")) as "first"
nth(compoundColumn," > ")[n] as "second"
from table
```

I've found lots of examples on here but they all seem to be saying to use the brackets but the brackets throw an error:

> Exception: Malformed SQL. More information: Error with SQL statement:
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '[1] as "first" from table where compoundColumn IS NOT NULL' at
>   line 3.

Comment: Not too familiar with MySQL but I don't think you need quotes around your column aliases ("first" and "second").

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: its cloudsql I think. (hard to tell, it is what is baked into this specific part of google app maker). Or alternately legacy sql if I want to include it as part of my Bigquery pull.

Comment: Send some sample data and also the data you expect, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got where I needed to go using regexp extract, in the bigquery pull rather than within appmaker:

```
SELECT 
  CompoundColumn,

  REGEXP_EXTRACT(CompoundColumn+">",  r'^(.*?)>') first_number,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(CompoundColumn+">",  r'^(?:(?:.*?)>){1}(.*?)>') second_number,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(CompoundColumn+">", r'^(?:(?:.*?)>){2}(.*?)>') third_number,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(CompoundColumn+">",  r'^(?:(?:.*?)>){3}(.*?)>') fourth_number
FROM
  myTable
WHERE
  CompoundColumn IS NOT NULL
```

The +">" part of the code is ugly but I couldn't get it to match strings that didn't end with the bracket (">?" breaks the whole thing) so I just made them all end with the bracket.

Answer (score 2):

- there's missing comma after "first" in your SQL
- I guess CloudSQL is based on some old version of MySQL which can split only using substring_index (see query below - yes it's verbose and clumsy, case clause must sanitize short strings)
- perhaps try brackets with `[offset(0)]` or `[ordinal(1)]`, that's what works for us, though we use Postgres dialect, also as #standardSql, not #legacySql

SQL from second point: ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b9ec/1))

```
select id,
  case when substring_index(cc,' > ',0) = cc then null else substring_index(substring_index(cc,' > ',1),' > ',-1) end as a1,
  case when substring_index(cc,' > ',1) = cc then null else substring_index(substring_index(cc,' > ',2),' > ',-1) end as a2,
  case when substring_index(cc,' > ',2) = cc then null else substring_index(substring_index(cc,' > ',3),' > ',-1) end as a3,
  case when substring_index(cc,' > ',3) = cc then null else substring_index(substring_index(cc,' > ',4),' > ',-1) end as a4,
  case when substring_index(cc,' > ',4) = cc then null else substring_index(substring_index(cc,' > ',5),' > ',-1) end as a5
from d
```

Comment: Alas legacy sql is not allowing me to use substring :/.

Answer (score 0):

The required *Legacy SQL* would be:

```
SELECT id, 
       compoundColumn,
       FIRST(SPLIT(compoundColumn, " > ")) AS "first",
       NTH(2, SPLIT(compoundColumn, " > ")) AS "second"
FROM table
```

See [this BigQuery documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql) for more info on the `SPLIT`, `FIRST` and `NTH` functions.